# calculate avg(value) for last 10 records postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, average, window-functions

i have a tricky task,
lets assume we have table "Racings", and there we have columns TRACK, CAR, CIRCLE_TIME
here is an example how data could be look like:

| id | track | car | circle_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 | 10 | 15 |
| 9 | 1 | 10 | 14 |
| 8 | 1 | 10 | 16 |
| 7 | 1 | 10 | 15 |
| 6 | 1 | 10 | 13 |
| 5 | 2 | 10 | 7 |
| 4 | 2 | 10 | 4 |
| 3 | 2 | 10 | 5 |
| 2 | 3 | 10 | 8 |
| 1 | 3 | 10 | 10 |

what i need, i to add one more coumn like avg3_circle_time which will show me an average time from last 3 circle_time from each track, example:

| id | track | car | circle_time | avg3_circle_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 | 10 | 15 | 15 |
| 9 | 1 | 10 | 14 | 15 |
| 8 | 1 | 10 | 16 | 14.6 |
| 7 | 1 | 10 | 15 | null |
| 6 | 1 | 10 | 13 | null |
| 5 | 2 | 10 | 7 | 5.3 |
| 4 | 2 | 10 | 4 | null |
| 3 | 2 | 10 | 5 | null |
| 2 | 3 | 10 | 8 | null |
| 1 | 3 | 10 | 10 | null |

I know how it could works in oracle, you could use something like rowid, but in case of postgresql i don't know, i have a draft like .....avg(circle_time) OVER(PARTITION BY track,car.....) as avg3_circle_time..... help me to solve that task please

Comment: How do you determine "last three"? I mean what determines if circle time 15 comes before 14?

Comment: @SalmanA ok get it, i've update my question and added id for the table, so we need to sort id descendly, so for example for the track 1 the last circle result is 15 with id 10, the first is 13 with id 6

Comment: The averages do not match either, but I'll assume you just entered random numbers.

Comment: Add an explicit window spec in `OVER()` , `ROWS BETWEEN..`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use window functions to calculate moving averages:

```sql
SELECT track, id, car, circle_time, AVG(circle_time) OVER (
  PARTITION BY track
  ORDER BY id
  ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
)
FROM t
ORDER BY track, id
```

Depending on your definition of previous three, the window could be `ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING`.

Comment: `CURRENT ROW` is the default frame end, so you could shorten `ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` to `ROWS 2 PRECEDING`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want only values when at least 3 circles available

```
select *
 , case when lag(id, 2) over(partition by TRACK, CAR order by id) is not null then 
        avg(CIRCLE_TIME) over(partition by TRACK, CAR order by id rows between 2 preceding and current row) end a
from Racing 
order by id desc;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=27d908a320633007d05f68c37f7f28b3)

Output

```
id  track   car circle_time a
10  1   10  15  15.0000000000000000
9   1   10  14  15.0000000000000000
8   1   10  16  14.6666666666666667
7   1   10  15  null
6   1   10  13  null
5   2   10  7   5.3333333333333333
4   2   10  4   null
3   2   10  5   null
2   3   10  8   null
1   3   10  10  null
```

Comment: `current row` is the default frame end, so you could shorten `rows between 2 preceding and current row` to `rows 2 preceding`.

Comment: Similarly, the condition `lag(id, 2) over(partition by TRACK, CAR order by id) is not null` could be shortened to `row_number() over(partition by TRACK, CAR order by id) > 2`, since you don't really care what the value of `id` is, you just want to check there are at least two preceding rows in the partition.

Comment: Also, the question asks for the average of the last three circle times of the track, independent of car, so it seems `CAR` should not be part of the partition - the question.

Comment: You could also use the `window` clause to avoid repeating the window definition.

Answer (score 1):

Use LAED() then checking one of the next 2 rows is NULL or not. THEN sum of three values for calculating average.

```
-- PostgreSQL
SELECT *
     , CASE WHEN next_circle_time IS NULL OR next_next_circle_time IS NULL
               THEN NULL
            ELSE ((t.circle_time + COALESCE(next_circle_time, 0) + COALESCE(next_next_circle_time, 0)) / 3 :: DECIMAL) :: DECIMAL(10, 1)
        END avg_circle_time
FROM (SELECT *
           , LEAD(circle_time, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY track ORDER BY id DESC) next_circle_time
           , LEAD(circle_time, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY track ORDER BY id DESC) next_next_circle_time
      FROM Racings) t
```

Another way Use AVG()

```
SELECT *
     , CASE WHEN LEAD(circle_time, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY track ORDER BY id DESC) IS NULL
                 OR LEAD(circle_time, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY track ORDER BY id DESC) IS NULL
               THEN NULL
            ELSE AVG(circle_time) OVER (PARTITION BY track ORDER BY id DESC ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 2 FOLLOWING)
       END :: DECIMAL(10, 2) avg_circle_time       
FROM Racings
```

Please check from url where **both query** exists https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=f0cd868623725a1b92bf988cfb2deba3

Answer (score 0):

Several of the posted answers end up repeating the window definition. You can avoid this with the `window` clause:

```
select *, 
   case when row_number() over(track_window) > 2 
        then trunc(avg(CIRCLE_TIME) over(track_window rows 2 preceding), 1)
   end a
from Racing 
window track_window as (partition by track order by id)
order by id desc
```

Note how, in this sample, `track_window` is defined once, then reused for both `row_number` and `avg`. In the latter case, the window clause is embellished with a frame as well (`rows 2 preceding`).